# Creating the IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Objects with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, keyvaluepair

For testing purposes, I need to create an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` object with the following sample key value pairs:

```
Key = Name | Value : John
Key = City | Value : NY
```

What is the easiest approach to do this?

Comment: Do you want to create `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T1,T2>>`? from which data source?

Comment: The initial data structure is not a problem. You may use any data source. The only requirement is to have an IEnumerable with above key value pairs :)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

any of:

```
values = new Dictionary<string,string> { {"Name", "John"}, {"City", "NY"} };
```

or

```
values = new [] {
      new KeyValuePair<string,string>("Name","John"),
      new KeyValuePair<string,string>("City","NY")
    };
```

or:

```
values = (new[] {
      new {Key = "Name", Value = "John"},
      new {Key = "City", Value = "NY"}
   }).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Answer (score 8):

`Dictionary<string, string>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`.

Answer (score 7):

```
var List = new List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> { 
  new KeyValuePair<String, String>("Name", "John"), 
  new KeyValuePair<String, String>("City" , "NY")
 };
```

Comment: Using a `KeyValuePair<string, string>[]` would probably be more efficient than using `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string,string> testDict = new Dictionary<string,string>(2);
testDict.Add("Name","John");
testDict.Add("City","NY");
```

Is that what you mean, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign a `Dictionary<K, V>` to `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K, V>>`

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

If that does not work you can try -

```
IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvp = dictionary.Select((pair) => pair);
```