# Setting IEnumerable KeyValuePair

Tags: c#-4.0, foreach, ienumerable, keyvaluepair

I have 2 `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TreeType, int>>` collections:

- **_myObject.Trees** - contains all the TreeTypes with values of 0.
- **newTrees** - can contain any number of TreeTypes with any int value.

Now what I want to do is simple but I've been trying for hours and can't quite get the desired results. I want to insert the newTrees values into the _myobject.Trees collection, so that the _myObject.Trees values won't all be 0.

The closest I've got is below. I know why this doesn't work, but again, I just can't see the solution.

```
    foreach (var tree in _myObject.Trees)
    {
        foreach (var newTree in newTrees)
        {
            if (tree.Key == newTree.Key)
            {
                _myObject.Trees[tree] =
                    new KeyValuePair<TreeType, int>(newTree.Key, newTree.Value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Would really appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like the following:

```
foreach (var tree in newTrees)
{
     var keyValuePair = _myObject.Trees.Where(s => s.Key == tree.Key).First();
     keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<Tree, int>(tree.Key, tree.Value);
}
```

Now you are looping only the `newTrees` and the `Where(...)` finds the corresponding element(s) in `_myObject.Trees` without explicitly looping.  Note that the call to `First()` assumes that any key in `newTrees` already exists in `_myObject.Trees` and that it exists only once.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and assistance (both you and varocarbas). I will be testing this within the hour (sorry for the delay), but 2 quick questions: I don't see how this actually changes the _myObject.Trees collection? Also, the _myObject.Trees collection is read-only..do I need to add a setter or can I get away without doing this? Thank you very much :)

Comment: Just tested and all works a treat! Again, thank you for the help. I appreciate it :]

Answer (score 1):

Although the Halvard approach provides a good solution for the main problem (+1 for him), it does not state clearly how to store the values in the target positions. Here you have a corrected version of Halvard's code relying on the most typical approach: a `Dictionary` ([one of the multiple posts talking about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654807/creating-the-ienumerablekeyvaluepairstring-string-objects-with-c)):

```
 Dictionary<TreeType, int> dict = _myObject.Trees.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
 foreach (var tree in newTrees)
 {
     var keyValuePair = _myObject.Trees.Where(s => s.Key == tree.Key);
     if (keyValuePair.Count() > 0)
     {
         dict[keyValuePair.First().Key] = tree.Value; //Value of the given tree associated with the current Key of _myObject.Trees
     }
 }

_myObject.Trees = dict;
```

Comment: +1 It seems more correct to only change the value like this rather than change the whole KeyValuePair like I did in my reply, but both solutions should give the same end result  (I did a minor edit to my code after your post).

Comment: @Halvard Thanks. For editing, it is a quicker approach (the one recommended everywhere). In any case, note that my original intention was doing things differently (iterating through the dictionary), but your loop is clearly better: a combination of both methods is the right solution here :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is a very nice way of solving my problem.

Comment: @user2439970 no problem. But the original loop was from Halvard, so he is the one deserving the award: well done.